# Yii dynamic checkbox

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have a column in my table named 'availability_option' with type enum('0', '1', '2'). Zero means 'Fixed Price', One means 'Auction', Two means 'Both'.
I want to generate 2 checkboxes dynamically One for Fixed Price and another 'Auction'.
How is it possible?
I didi it static.
But it should not be the right syntax of yii.

```
<input value="0" id="fixedprice" type="checkbox" name="ProductShop[availability_option][]">
<label for="fixedprice">Fixed Price</label>
<input value="1" id="auctionprice" type="checkbox" name="ProductShop[availability_option][]">
<label for="auctionprice">Auction</label>
```

I want it dynamically, So how is it possible?Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkboxList()`:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->inline(true)->checkboxList([0 => 'Fixed Price', 1 => 'Auction']) ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#inline%28%29-detail

Comment: By using this my checkboxes is not showing, but text is visible.

Comment: @SubhankarBhattacharjee remove inline not needed.  i have already tested, show how you tried.

Comment: Using checkboxList yii dynamically create div and labels. Is it possible to remove those label and add label for on these? If, it is possible then my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing The same problem and I solved It by doing like this :

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'name[]')->checkboxList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C']); ?>
```

Note that the checkboxList expects the first argument of the passed array to be of string type as well so you may need to make changes to your array.

Generated HTML will  be as:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="fomrmName[name][]" value="'1'"> a</label>
```

another way by which I solved My problem was to wrap the checkbox in foreach block like following:

```
<?php foreach($vendorsData as $value){?>
<li><?= $form->field($ucVendors, 'vendor_id['.$value.']')->checkbox(array('label'=>$value)); ?>
```

and the Generated html is as:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="usedcarvendors-vendor_id-value" name="UsedCarVendors[vendor_id][value]" value="1"> value</label>
```

[Reference Link here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-activeform-input-fields/#Checkbox-List-Input-Field)